# How to prevent enum parameter type for Camel swagger 2.16.2

Tags: java, apache-camel, swagger

I switched from `Apache Camel` `2.16.0` to `2.16.2` and now all my parameters get an additional empty `enum` even when no `allowedValues` are specified. Now Swagger UI displays an empty dropdown for all dataTypes. I do not think that is supposed to happen is it? Am I overseeing something?

From *camel-example-swagger-java*:

```html
<!-- this is a rest GET to view an user by the given id -->
<get uri="/{id}" outType="org.apache.camel.example.rest.User">
    <description>Find user by id</description>
    <param name="id" type="path" description="The id of the user to get" dataType="integer"/>
    <responseMessage message="The user that was found"/>
    <responseMessage code="404" message="User not found"/>
    <route>
      <to uri="bean:userService?method=getUser(${header.id})"/>
      <filter>
        <simple>${body} == null</simple>
        <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE">
          <constant>404</constant>
        </setHeader>
      </filter>
    </route>
</get>
```

This is what is generated, mind the empty `enum`:

```js
"parameters" : [ {
  "name" : "id",
  "in" : "path",
  "description" : "The id of the user to get",
  "required" : true,
  "type" : "integer",
  "enum" : [ ]
} ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is fixed in 2.17-SNAPSHOT, I guess I will have to wait for the next release.